# Selecting SVG items using D3 DataMaps?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at the [Data Maps](http://datamaps.github.io/) library of D3, and I would like to know how to go about manipulating the svg content. Let's say I look at the basic world map, how would I run a `alert("Selected")` by clicking on Canada? Or change its background color by clicking on it?

EDIT: In my specific instance, I am using the US map. I use the following lines to boot up the map:

```
var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('maincontains'),
scope: 'usa',
fills: {defaultFill: 'rgb(217, 217, 217)'}
});
```

Now, in the [`usa.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/master/dist/datamaps.usa.min.js) I find IDs such as "NY". However, this does not allow me to

`document.getElementById("NY").addEventListener('click', function(){
alert("New York");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) on *Events* says the following:

> All events are bubbled up to the root svg element and to listen to
>   events, use the done callback.

So in order to bind a click event and alert the name, use the `done` event of the `map` object and use the `svg` object inside the event handler:

```
<script>
    var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        done: function(datamap) {
            datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
                alert(geography.properties.name);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

My example click on *Greenland*:

[image]

Further restrictions (e.g. only specific countries) could be made using the properties.